# Javascript only first one (not all) instances on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a list item, based on the text within the list `<p>`. I have it almost right. However, my current version doesn't find every instance on a page. It finds, and hides, the last instance, but not the others. There can be 3-4 of these on a page I would like to hide.

Help appreciated.

```js
// select relevant elements
var elements = $('p');

// go through the elements and find the one with the value
elements.each(function(index, domElement) {
    var $element = $(domElement);

    // does the element have the text we're looking for?
    if ($element.text() === "Happy New Year (Southern)") {
        $element.parent().hide();
            // hide the element with jQuery
        return false; 
            // jump out of the each
    }
});
```

Comment: You can make elements an array by calling `elements.toArray()` (non-mutating).

Comment: What about using filter first, and then only hiding that?

Comment: `return false` ends the `.each()` iteration

Comment: You seem to know that, since you commented "jump out of the each". If you want to hide them all, why are you ending the loop?

Comment: Just get rid of `return false;` and it will hide all of them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the `return false;` as [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said in the comments ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70572197/javascript-only-first-one-not-all-instances-on-page/70572505#comment124753007_70572197), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70572197/javascript-only-first-one-not-all-instances-on-page/70572505#comment124753057_70572197)):

> `return false` ends the `.each()` iteration

> Just get rid of `return false;` and it will hide all of them.

Answer (score 0):

What about using filter first, and then only hiding the elements after that?

```js
// select relevant elements
var elements = $('p');

// go through the elements and find the one with the value
elements.filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).text() === "Happy New Year (Southern)";
}).eq(0).parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Happy New Year (Northern)</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Happy New Year (Eastern)</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Happy New Year (Southern)</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Happy New Year (Southern)</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Happy New Year (Southern)</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Happy New Year (Western)</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using `.eq(0)` we select only the "first" matched item, and then hide the parent.

To hide all of them, we just omit the `.eq(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
var elements   = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var searchText = "Happy New Year (Southern)";

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements.textContent == searchText) {
        elements[i].parent().hide()
    }
}
```